# Jersey 2.x throws NegativeArraySizeException when try to logging request, for non-GET requests, with SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jersey-2.0, log4j2

Since Jersey 2.x deprecated LoggingFilter in latest release, we went ahead with Jersey's own request/response logging, along with log4j2. We are using springboot. Problem arises when we hit web service with POST method, it throws NegativeArraySizeException

```
java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    at org.glassfish.jersey.logging.LoggingInterceptor.logInboundEntity(LoggingInterceptor.java:210) ~[jersey-common-2.23.2.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.logging.ServerLoggingFilter.filter(ServerLoggingFilter.java:108) ~[jersey-common-2.23.2.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerFilteringStage.apply(ContainerFilteringStage.java:132) ~[jersey-server-2.23.2.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerFilteringStage.apply(ContainerFilteringStage.java:68) ~[jersey-server-2.23.2.jar:?]
```

My log4j2 configuration -

```
<!-- Jersey logger -->
<AsyncLogger name="org.glassfish" level="all" additivity="false">
    <AppenderRef ref="Console" level="off" />
    <AppenderRef ref="RollingFileIO" level="all" />
</AsyncLogger>
```

If I set log level to `off`, everything works fine.
SpringBoot version `1.4.3`

Just for a safe check, I am able to see incoming data in Wireshark.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got the answer. To let jersey write the logging, we were registering this -

```
     jerseyConfig.register(
        new LoggingFeature(          
          java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LoggingFeature.DEFAULT_LOGGER_NAME),
          java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, 
          LoggingFeature.Verbosity.PAYLOAD_ANY, 
          Integer.MAX_VALUE)
       );
```

Here, 4th param is `maxEntitySize`, which is Integer.MAX_VALUE. So, while creating logging buffer, jersey is initialising array with `maxEntity + 1`, which was causing the exception.

I changed this value to some lower/logical number, and things are working fine.